# Contextual menu Mac OS X - Pasting a text string

Tags: string, macos, menu, replace

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a contextual menu option that allows me to select a string, e.g. from BBEdit or TextEdit etc., and after selecting it > right click > call Contextual menu item > Paste/Replace with string of text.

For example, if I had a text file open and wanted to select the word "blue" I would like the contextual menu item to be able to replace that with "red."

Yes, this is like copy and pasting, but there's a reason I am asking for this specifically and it would save me tons of time at my job.

I am not an experienced programmer, so consider me to be a complete newbie.

I want to do this in Automator. I know all the steps to get to the building part, just don't know which Utilities item to use for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out how to do it with a keyboard shortcut, though I'd also like to have a universal right-click contextual menu option. I used to use some app to do this for me in the old days.

Here's what I did. Go to Automator, select "no input" and "any application" above the actions window.

On the left, click on Utilities, drag "Run AppleScript" into the window on the right.

Insert, into the middle:
    tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "Text You Want To Input"
    end tell


Save it, then go to System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts > Services, and find your saved title. Create a keyboard shortcut.